# ListView SubItems in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, listview

I started learning WPF c#, in Windows Form I was adding SubItems to ListView like this

```
string[] spendDetails = new string[2];
spendDetails[0] = _categoryNames[0];
spendDetails[1] = _categoryValues[0].ToString();
 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(spendDetails);
_listSpendingView.Items.Add(item);
```

I couldn't do this in WPF, so how can I add SubItems to ListView in WPF?

Comment: "I couldn't do this in WPF" , why not ?  `ListView1.Items.Add()` do exists in WPF

Comment: @styx it worked, do you know how can I check on subItem Text?

Comment: `ListView.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text`

Comment: @styx There is no 'SubItems' at all, also no 'Text' I just saw content

Comment: you can iterate over the items list or view the SelectedItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{   
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Demo

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var item = new ItemViewModel()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "User" + i,
                Age = 8 + i
            };
            this.ListView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you should just have to

```
_listSpendingView.Items.Add(_categoryNames[0]);
```

The Items collection will hold the element for later retrieval and will call ToString() automatically for displaying.

Comment: Does that mean, that you use ListView with a GridView? If that's true, please show how you defined it.